# Error while building android chrome cast video example

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

Hi I trying chrome cast device with Google's https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android this sample. I have imported `appcompat` and `mediarouter` from V7 lib. I also imported `google play service lib` and `CastCompanionLibrary-android`. All libs are proper and without any error. But when I tried to build video sample it gives me some resources error in `styles-castvideo.xml`. It gives error for following resources

```
  <style name="ShowcaseView">
    <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title</item>
    <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail</item>
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#CC000000</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonText">@string/ok</item>
    <item name="sv_showcaseColor">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

Am I missing something. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: You have already opened a ticket on that project (as you should have, that has been answered as well) so why are you posting an identical question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowcaseView should be added as library.
https://github.com/naddaf/ShowcaseView
Dependencies

CastCompanionLibrary-android: can be downloaded here at https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

ShowcaseView (see change list 1.1 -> 1.2 for details)